# Why does descendent selector "p p" not work?

Tags: html, css

I am testing out descendant selector priorities,  and so I have this code:

```
p p {background-color: blue}
p {background-color: purple}
```

However, it seems that even if I nest `<p>` inside another `<p>` it's always purple. When I tried it with span (span span), the descendant selector double span took priority over the single span. In this case, the `<p>` is never blue. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: p inside p isn't allowed

Comment: @TemaniAfif Are there other rules like this that isn't allowed? Or if you could point be somewhere would be nice. The information I saw on descendant selectors never mentioned this.

Comment: Saw your edit, thanks

Comment: In your CSS you have written    " p p {background-color: blue}"    in first line it should be after     "p {background-color: purple}"    .

Comment: @AjayMalhotra No I wrote in same order for span but it worked, the descendant should have higher priority.

Comment: Yes you are correct